# Is there a command in Shell scripting for executing .exe file and running commands automatically inside of it? replacing the user interaction

Tags: windows, bash, shell, command-line

I have a .sh script file that I'm modifying which runs an .EXE file that opens the Windows command line prompt automatically.

This .exe asks the user for an input (name of the file in the folder workspace that it will read)

I want to automate this step in my shell script so my user doesn't have to interact with this, and run the commands automatically

I read a bit about the expect command but I think that is for Linux only.

Can someone help me, I'm pretty new to Shell scripting and I couldn't find any useful information elsewhere.

Comment: See https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your executable accepts command-line arguments. So, here we go.

You can use the **"start"** command in Windows Shell. For example:

```
start C:\path\to\program.exe -argument
```

If you want to make the script wait until the .exe file finishes running before continuing, you can use the **"/wait"** command:

```
start /wait C:\path\to\program.exe -argument
```

*IF* all of that doesn't work, please try:

```
start myprogram.exe /command1 /command2 /command3
```

Hope it helps,